# Finding words with Three consecutive alphabetical letters

Tags: c

> Write a function that prints out all the words in the array passed in as an argument that contain a sequence of 3 consecutive letters that are also consecutive alphabetically. For instance, the word costume should be printed, but not cost. The Array will end with Null which can be used to terminate the algorithm

Comment: Look at your `a == b == c`. That is not good C.

Comment: `(int)words[i][j+2];` invokes *Undefined Behavior* attempting to read beyond the end of the string. (`j+1` is the *nul-terminating* character)

Comment: Technically, you want `words[i] != NULL` instead of `words[i] != '\0'` and the conversion from `char` to `int` is unnecessary. A comparison of `words[i][j] == words[i][j+1]` is fine (after you fix your indexing problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(asciiOne == asciiTwo -1 == asciiThree -2 || asciiOne == asciiTwo -1 == asciiThree -2)`

This is incorrect in C. If first condition is satisfied(`asciiOne == asciiTwo -1`) then it will give 1. After that, it will check `1 == asciiThree -2` which is ofcourse not what we want. The correct way to do this is:

`if((asciiOne == asciiTwo -1) && (asciiTwo == asciiThree -1))`

This way it evaluate both conditions which are required in the problem.

Edit - Added brackets to specify in what order conditions will be evaluated. We can also remove brackets since precedence of `==` is higher than `&&`. Source - [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Also describe to put brackets around the `&&` conditions so the `|| condition will be evaluated in the right order, as a just for clarity way of writing.